# how to create procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating procedure in mysql. but I am facing some issues while creating that.

I am applying query i.e

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc( param1 INT) BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO param1 FROM 91_nidhi; END//
```

and The error is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; c
heck the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: You need a delimiter at the stat `delimiter //`

Comment: If you use line breaks, the code will be more readable and you will get a line number in the error message that is actually useful.

Comment: okay now it is working but can you please tell how can i call this procedure ??

Comment: No this procedure is not created.  how can i create properly

Comment: @NidhiSen just posted an answer check this how to create and execute the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you need to do
- You are not passing any input value rather you are using an output value
- so specify the param as OUT

Below is the example

```
mysql> create table 91_nidhi (id int,val varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into 91_nidhi values (1,'aa'),(2,'bb'),(3,'cc');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now lets create the procedure

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc( out param1 INT) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM 91_nidhi; 
END; //
```

Then change the delimiter in the terminal as

```
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Now lets call the procedure

```
mysql> call simpleproc(@res);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @res ;
+------+
| @res |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```